# Bash script to extract lines between two different timestamps in a log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to extract lines between two different relative timestamps, I've written a bash script, but it doesn't work properly; please let me know How I can do it correctly.

My log file looks like this:

```
22/06/23 19:30:21        [Logs...]
22/06/24 17:58:30        [Logs...]
22/06/24 17:59:48        [Logs...]
22/06/24 18:11:27        [Logs...]
22/06/24 18:11:28        [Logs...]
```

the code which is not working properly:

command:    `./test.sh -t 22/06/24,17:58:00-22/06/24,18:11:59`

Code:

```
#! /bin/bash
    #INPUT: 22/06/24,17:58:00-22/06/24,18:11:30
    #startDate=22/06/24
    startDate=$(echo $2 | cut -d "-" -f 1 | cut -d "," -f 1)
    
    #endDate=22/06/24
    endDate=$(echo $2 | cut -d "-" -f 2 | cut -d "," -f 1)
    
    #startTime=17:58:00
    startTime=$(echo $2 | cut -d "-" -f 1 | cut -d "," -f 2)
    
    #endTime=18:11:30
    endTime=$(echo $2 | cut -d "-" -f 2 | cut -d "," -f 2)
    
    #Script Parameter Format to search in Log Files: YY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss-YY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss
    
    #timestampStart=22-06-24 17:58:00
    timestampStart=$(echo $startDate | cut -d "/" -f 1)-$(echo $startDate | cut -d "/" -f 2)-$(echo $startDate | cut -d "/" -f 3)" "$startTime
    
    #timestampEnd=22-06-24 18:11:27
    timestampEnd=$(echo $endDate | cut -d "/" -f 1)-$(echo $endDate | cut -d "/" -f 2)-$(echo $endDate | cut -d "/" -f 3)" "$endTime
    
    #tstart=1656077280
    tStart=`date --date="$timestampStart" +%s`
    
    #tEnd=1656078090
    tEnd=`date --date="$timestampEnd" +%s`
    
    while read -r line; do
      re="[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"
      if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
    
        #searchDate="22/06/24 17:58:00"
        searchDate=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f 1,2)
    
        #searchTime="22-06-24 17:58:00"
        searchTime=$(echo $searchDate | cut -d "/" -f 1)-$(echo $searchDate | cut -d "/" -f 2)-$(echo $searchDate | cut -d "/" -f 3)
        #tSearch=1656077280
        tSearch=`date --date="$searchTime" +%s`
      fi
    
      #if 1656077280>=1656077280 AND 1656077280<=1656078090
      if  [ $tSearch -gt $tStart ] && [ $tSearch -lt $tEnd ];then
    
        #22/06/24 17:58:00       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
        echo $line
      fi
    done < /oracleAS10g/product/opmn/logs/OC4J~officeauto~default_island~1
```

Output Error:

```
./test.sh: line 43: [: -gt: unary operator expected
```

Expected output: shows the lines between two timestamps that are specified

```
22/06/24 17:58:30        [Logs...]
22/06/24 17:59:48        [Logs...]
22/06/24 18:11:27        [Logs...]
```

Comment: thanks, I added the "Expected Output" part to my post, I need to show only the lines between two timestamps that are specified

Comment: to enable debug mode add `set -xv` at the top of the script, run the script again and peruse the output; I'm guessing one of your variables is blank/empty so instead of a test like  `[ 5 -gt 10 ]` it actually looks like `[  -gt 10 ]`; (`set +xv` to disable debug mode)

Comment: From the error message, we can conclude that `tSearch` must be empty. This happens, when the `if` block has not been executed during the first iteration of the loop - a very likely scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` is good for exact pattern matching, but for comparing values "greater than" or "less than", you might find it easier to use `grep` or `awk`. For example, given the input (space between date & time, tab separating timestamp from log entry):

```
$ cat foo.txt
22/06/23 19:30:21   [Logs ... 5]
22/06/24 17:58:30   [Logs ... 4]
22/06/24 17:59:48   [Logs ... 3]
22/06/24 18:11:27   [Logs ... 2]
22/06/24 18:11:28   [Logs ... 1]
```

you could use `sed` as shown in the other answer (which I'll extend to `awk` by comparison):

```
$ sed -n '\#22/06/24 17:58:30#, \#22/06/24 18:11:27#p' foo.txt
22/06/24 17:58:30   [Logs ... 4]
22/06/24 17:59:48   [Logs ... 3]
22/06/24 18:11:27   [Logs ... 2]
```

It's basically:

```
$ sed -n '/pattern1/, /pattern2/p' file.txt
```

Note the tricky part about needing to change the `/pattern1/, /pattern2/` to something that would allow slash (`/`) in the search pattern. Pick one that's best for your data. I'm using `#` here.

Using `awk` is about the same, except allowing `/` in the search pattern is a little different; so,

```
$ awk -F'\t' '/pattern1/, /pattern2/' file.txt
```

becomes, in order to allow `/` in the pattern:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$0~v1, $0~v2' v1="pattern1" v2="pattern2" file.txt
```

But this just matches lines between two patterns, and the patterns must match exactly. We could treat the timestamps like alphanumeric patterns, and match lines "greater than" `pattern1`  up to lines "less than" `pattern2`:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$1>=v1 && $1<=v2' v1="22/06/24 17:58:30"  v2="22/06/24 18:11:27" foo.txt  
22/06/24 17:58:30   [Logs ... 4]
22/06/24 17:59:48   [Logs ... 3]
22/06/24 18:11:27   [Logs ... 2]
```

But it's an alphanumeric comparison, so you can use other dates like search patterns:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$1>=v1 && $1<=v2' v1="22/06/24 00:00:00"  v2="22/06/24 18:00:00" foo.txt  
22/06/24 17:58:30   [Logs ... 4]
22/06/24 17:59:48   [Logs ... 3]
```

You can switch the `>=` and `<=` to just simple `>` and `<` depending on whether you want to include the given date or not.

Comment: note that one big assumption is that the timestamp is separated from the log entry by a tab. If that's not the case, you'll have to modify the field separator (`awk -F...`) and field selection (the `$1` is the entire timestamp, but you might have date & time in separate fields)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple `awk` would do the job here:

```bash
awk -v d1="22/06/24 17:58:30" -v d2="22/06/24 18:11:30" '
($1 " " $2) >= d1 && ($1 " " $2) <= d2' file

22/06/24 17:58:30        [Logs...]
22/06/24 17:59:48        [Logs...]
22/06/24 18:11:27        [Logs...]
22/06/24 18:11:28        [Logs...]
```

Comment: thanks this works! I've tried sed with these patterns (sed -n "|$a|,|$b|p" file.log) and (sed -n "/$a/,/$b/p" file.log) none of them worked. 
this was a life-changing answer, thanks again

Comment: This command works well when you specify the exact time, but the user usually knows the relative time, it did not work for me.

Comment: Can you clarify this new requirement by showing some example data in question

Comment: Thanks again; I edited my questions. In fact, The user enters relative time as an input, expecting to see all the lines in this relative time interval.

Comment: But it should print `22/06/24 18:11:28` also right?

Comment: yes, for example the user enters :22/06/24 17:30:00 - 22/06/24 18:30:00 but in the output it should print lines that have timestamps in between like 22/06/24 17:58:30...22/06/24 18:11:27

Comment: I had to step away for some work. Have edited my answer to handle range scenario